# Add special character at end of input fields string, jquery automatically adding comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am adding % symbol at the end of the string on keyup event, first I get the current value of input field and then split('%') and then I use following code

```
$('.percent input[type=text]').val(str+'%');
```

But this also adding comma after newly added character.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uU8Lf/1/)

Also Would love to do it by using css but the condition is only that there should not be any image used for it neither positioning used.(Can I use :after or :befor)

Comment: it would be much easier to take that percentage sign out of the input and put it after it

Comment: @slash: yes slash I know that but I thought I will look good if I included it inside input field as my Input field using customized style

Comment: 1. doesn't look better; 2. it is complicating the user experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the problem was the split function.
Try this:

```
$('.percent input[type=text]').on('keyup',function(){
            var oldstr=$('.percent input[type=text]').val();
            var str=oldstr.replace('%',''); 
            $('.percent input[type=text]').val(str+'%');        
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `.split()` method returns comma seperated data, that is why your data is comma seperated.
If all you wish to do is remove the first symbol you could use `.substr()` - read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.percent input[type=text]').on('keyup',function(e){
            var oldstr=$('.percent input[type=text]').val();
            var tokens = oldstr.split('%');
            var suffix = tokens.pop() + '%';
            var prefix = tokens.join("");
            $('.percent input[type=text]').val(prefix+suffix);
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uU8Lf/4/

Answer (score 0):

A little late now, however I couldn't help but notice the constant reuse of the element's class/type throughout both answers. Is it not beneficial/best practice to use 'this' keyword within the '.on' callback function like so:

```
$('.percent input[type=text]').on('keyup',function(){
    var oldstr=$(this).val();
    var str=oldstr.replace('%',''); 
    $(this).val(str+'%');        
});
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong, and yes, I'm being picky here :)